# GWT : Difference b/w addMouseOutHandler and addDomHandler

Tags: gwt, mouseevent, handler

I want to implement the `onMouseOut` method to hide the popup.

What is the difference b/w this two approaches..?

**1. addMouseOutHandler**

```
actionsPopup.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {         
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            actionsPopup.hide();
        }
    });
    });
```

**2. addDOMHandler**

```
 actionsPopup.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {         
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            actionsPopup.hide();
        }
    });
    }, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference. If you look into the GWT code of basic widgets (like FocusPanel) the implementation of the addMouseOutHandler just calls addDomHandler:

```
public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
}
```

But by using the [HasMouseOutHandlers](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasMouseOutHandlers.html) interface, your code will have more flexibility. For example you can use the @UiHandler annotation. Or you can also see your widget like a 'HasMouseOutHandlers' instance in order to group some treatments. By the way, in the signature of your object, you indicate clearly to others developers that your object can receive this type of event.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same thing at runtime. Although it is a better design to use the typed version with addMouseOutHandler.